# Firebase auth crash when initialize providers (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add authentication in my app via Firebase Auth. 
I'm experiencing some problems, here the code:

```
private List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(), <----- ERROR
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());
}
```

The error log is this:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference

Here is my Gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following dependency:

```
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

The above dependency is the very old firebase dependency, you need to check here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

To know how to setup the firebase dependency

---

This seems like a new project, so migrate to androidx, then use the following `firebaseui` dependency:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'
```

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: I did the migration, and edited gradle: 
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'
}
the error is the same.